# Is there a way to get the outer height of a skewed element using vanilla JavasScript?

Tags: javascript, css, height, css-transforms, skew

When using `getComputedStyle` to fetch the height of an element which has been skewed (`transform: skewY(-10deg)`) then the value is the height of the element before the transform. e.g. a `div` in my case which is 600px high but which covers around 700px in vertical space. Is there a way to get the actual rendered height?

Comment: Interesting question! It would probably be improved / made easier to answer with a tiny [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/) example of the skewed element, ideally in the context where you're using it (because maybe we can get there via the context).

Answer (score 0):

I've since found the solution: `element.getBoundingClientRect().height`.